# how to solve nodejs $lte end variable

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I'm working on a mean stack project my front end is ready and works perfectly and the backend works perfectly too but the error comes after relating them
I got an error which I do not know where it comes I found in in nodejs terminal when I make a request from the front

```
{ end: { '$lte': '2020-11-26' } }
```

this is how  i match the front and back in a `envirement.js` file

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
serverurl:'http://localhost:5000/api/post/api'


};
```

I need some help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition should be like

```
{ end: { $lte: '2020-11-26' } }
```

The condition operator should not be the string. It's constant/variable.
Please check here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/